# Partition MacBook Pro without 10.6 disc

Tags: macos, mac

I've just bought a MacBook Pro that came with OSX 10.5 install disks. The system on the computer is 10.6 but I don't have the disks.

I want to partion the disk but don't want to lose the OS X 10.6.

I have some programmes (CS2) that I think will run on 10.5 but probably not 10.6. Do I need to acquire a Firewire HD to copy the 10.6 software?

Answer (score 2):

You could ask the person who sold you the MacBook if they still have the discs.

If they're not there anymore: If they sold the license to you, you can basically download a 10.6 installer "somewhere else" on the Internet and use that. (The actual installation medium isn't tied to the license—anyone can lose or scratch their discs.)

In order to reinstall OS X you'd have to either burn the disk images to a DVD, or restore them onto a drive which you can then [boot from USB](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1948). Note that in order to partition the system you have to start *Disk Utility* from the setup after you've booted from the installation medium.

> I have some programmes (CS2) that I think will run on 10.5 but probably not 10.6

I don't understand why you'd want to reinstall 10.6 then and not go back to 10.5. Have you tried the programs? If you're already on 10.6 you can install them and see if they work.